# Compile c codes when linking to gsl library with R CMD SHLIB

Tags: r, c, compilation, gsl

I have written a R code which interfaces with c code. The c code links to GNU Scientific Library (GSL). I have no problem compiling things and running codes on my Mac. Therefore the codes themselves should have no problem. However, when I submit codes to Linux server, I'm not able to compile.
On server, I find the path to gsl library by

```
[user@server]$ gsl-config --libs
-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
[user@server]$ gsl-config --cflags
-I/usr/include
```

I have tried the following commands in Terminal to compile c.

```
R CMD SHLIB example.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
PKG_LIBS="-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm" R CMD SHLIB example.c
PKG_LIBS="-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm" PKG_CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include" R CMD SHLIB example.c
```

They all give me the following warning. But I do get the .o and .so files.

```
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c example.c -o example.o
example.c: In function ‘GXE_mcmc’:
example.c:571:3: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
   /*printf("The updated value of a is %lf\n",*a);
 ^
example.c:591:3: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
   /* printf("Updated freq.out is as below\n");
 ^
example.c: In function ‘GXE_update_randomA’:
example.c:1528:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gsl_ran_multivariate_gaussian’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    gsl_ran_multivariate_gaussian(r,mean_vec,mnorm_cov_mat,randomA_result);
    ^
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o example.so example.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

When I try 'dyn.load(example.so)', I have the following error.

```
Error in dyn.load("example.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/user/01_07/example.so':
  /home/user/01_07/example.so: undefined symbol: gsl_ran_multivariate_gaussian
```

It seems the gsl library has not been correctly linked. Does anyone has some suggestions? I really appreciate!

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /home/user/01_07/example.so`? Generally I find it easier to use an R package instead of `R CMD SHLIB`, but this should not be the issue here.

Comment: You should tke the "implicit declaration warning" seriously. Either you are not including the correct headers, or the GSL version on your Linux server does not have that particular function.

Comment: Hi Ralf, here is part of the ldd output
 `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd41f60000)
 libgsl.so.0 => /lib64/libgsl.so.0 (0x00002b60b8d7b000)
 libgslcblas.so.0 => /lib64/libgslcblas.so.0 (0x00002b60b91a4000)`

Comment: I'm new to making R packages. But definitely I'll try that if compilation won't work. @Ralf Stubner

Comment: Which GSL versions are you using on Mac and Linux? `gsl-config —version` can tell you. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I realize that GSL version on the server is 1.15, whereas on my Mac is 2.6. The old version does not provide the function I need. I'm not a root user so I probably would contact them to see if they can update the library.